# why is my python re pattern not working for splitting at spaces?

Tags: python, split, space, spaces, python-re

im trying to split text at all punctuation for english and russian. this works except for with spaces. for some reason \s is not working. allRussianWords ends up containing spaces but I do not want it to.
`allRussianWords = re.split("[—…();«»!?.:,%\s\n]",words)`

this is the string that i am attempting to split
`words = "привет, моё имя Мэтт. Как ты?"`
the punctuation is in russian

Comment: Why not `re.findall(r"\b\w+?\b", words)` instead?

Comment: it did not work. i think that maybe the russian characters are messing that up

Comment: Does `allRussionWords` contain spaces or empty strings?  The way it looks like `re.split` will work in this case is if it encounters two consecutive separaters it will generate and empty string for the second one.

Comment: Okay, what is your Python version, and does the string contain non-breaking spaces by any chance?

Comment: the string that i have is this

Comment: привет, моё имя Мэтт. Как ты?

Comment: python version 3.8

Comment: When I try this I don't get spaces, but I do get empty match groups wherever there is punctuation.

Comment: That might be what I'm getting to. I'm trying to create a mysql query with this and I end up getting select statements that are blank because because spaces or empty match groups are in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need a + after the closing square bracket, to match consecutive characters. One of the other answers points this out, too.

The \n is also redundant, as \s contains the line return character.